# Samsung SmartTV SEF Player handle keydown

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

How to handle keydown events for Samsung SmartTV SEF Player ([link](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00014/Player_215.html))?

I tried:

**Markup**:

```
<object id="pluginObjectPlayer" border=0 classid="clsid:SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-PLAYER" style="position:absolute;z-index:1;left:0px;top:0px;width:1280px;height:720px"></object>
```

**Code**:

```
var player = document.getElementById('pluginObjectPlayer'); //get player object
player.Play(streamUrl); //start playback
$("body").focus(); //focus on html element which can handle keydown events
```

Doesn't works. Playback starts normally, but keydown event is not handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SEF Player doesn't have any event key handlers, the key event will catched by the scene/main javascript code and need to do the action by code with the player API. For example to stop the playback :

```
case sf.key.STOP:
player.Stop();
break;
```